# Is there a way where I can change the view controller on another iPhone using Core Bluetooth in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

Am trying to create an app where I can use Core Bluetooth to change from one View Controller to another on a different device that am connected to using Core Bluetooth. For example, I press a button on one iPhone and it would change "HomeViewController1" to "HomeViewController2" on the other connected iPhone. Anyone has an idea of how to go about it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple thing to do with Core Bluetooth once you have your `CoreBluetooth` stack setup and working.

You would setup one iPhone as a `CBPeripheral` and the other iPhone as a `CBCentral` would scan for and discover the `CBPeripheral` then connect to it. Once you have the connection between 2 iPhones, it's just a matter of monitoring and changing a variable in the `CBPeripheral`. When it changes, you update your views.

Comment: I know this was a little while ago, but i tried something like this. Where if am connected to the device i would simply change a variable in the CBPeripheral and i had a protocol to monitor the change of that variable. Sometimes it would work, other times it wouldn't, although there was nothing to interfere with the bluetooth connection. Would you happen to know what could have been the cause?

Comment: No sorry. Just use plenty of `print` statements to check your devices have actually connected and the Peripheral and Characteristics discovered. Be sure to use `setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:` when changing the value so it fires a notification.